# Micro + restricted user Win XP = avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding

Tags: arduino-micro, installation

I have a Micro (original) and I am (trying to) using it under windows XP.
I was successful in installing its drivers (by swithching to ad Admin account) and uploading sketches to it, no problem. Even when I switched to my limited account, I was able to upload new sketches without error.

But...

Everytime I reboot my computer, as soon as I connect the Micro to the usb port, I get a "New hardware found" popup window from Windows. If I ignore the window I do not see the board in Arduino's IDE. If I choose to install the drivers (by loggin in that window as an admin and then fetching them from the Arduino folder) I end up seeing the board, selecting the COM port and then when compiling, getting the dreadful

```
avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

If I press the reset button I get the "Found new hardware window" again and the cycle repeats.

To make it work again I have to log off, log in in an admin user account, and install the friggin drivers from there. After that, if I log off and enter into my limited account, I can see board, port and I can finally upload my sketches (or at least that was the case the last two times).

Is it supposed to work this way?
Can I make it work like a Nano: install drivers **only once** and then just use the board?

PS
I have to mention that I happen to have 5 compatible Nanos with a ch340G chipset that work like a charm (and cost one tenth of the Micro). I installed the drivers ONCE and forgot about that.
I also happen to have a keyboard and a mouse, and they do not require me to install their drivers every time I plug the USB connector off.
Why is the Micro misbehaving this way?